# Dropping a connection upon event

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell-script, networking

Is it possible to drop a number of connections when establishing new ones? For example, suppose we have a set of remote workstations with addresses `{A, B, C}` and another set with hosts `{D, E}`. We assume we are connected to A, B and C and connect to D and/or E. How can the connections to A, B and C be dropped upon establishing connections to D and E?

It is best if the process that opened the connections is not terminated.

Comment: Do you mean SSH connections?

Comment: No, not necessarily. A client running under the same process is performing all these connections. I want to drop them once new connections to D and E are established.

Comment: what connection means here? do you mean http connection? or a connection on some custom port?

Comment: A TCP connection on a custom port.

Comment: @Ijaz Khan all connections are made by the same process.

Comment: From the point of view of the local system, are the connections created by a local process doing a `connect`, or by it doing an `accept`?

Comment: By a doing a connect to an accept()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, with `iptables` you can't kill established connections. After a connection is open (let's say, a download) and you create a rule with the `FORWARD` target dropping the connection, it will apply only for new connections.
The only way to do this is:

1. Killing the process that is creating the connection
2. Shutting down the interface

There are some scenarios where people related that even [creating a route](http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1220384) with the reject option, executing [ifdown](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1345837) on an interface or removing a masquerade postrouting rule didn't close the connections.

About the condition, the nearest thing I can imagine to create a condition on `iptables` whenever something happens, can be done by using the [condition](http://www.netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.2) match of Netfilter Extensions

This example will reject new connections whenever the server is in maintenance. Is just a matter of echoing a number 1 to a file inside `/proc` with the same name of the condition.

```
# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.1.10 --dport http -m condition --condition webdown -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset

# echo 1 > /proc/net/ipt_condition/webdown
```